# can't get image to load

Tags: django, django-models, django-2.0

I probably did something stupid but when i upload a image with /admin I can't get it to load.

I made a for loop to get all post's and everything shows except for the image

model:

```
`class Post(models.Model):
    title   =   models.CharField(max_length=140)
    body    =   models.TextField()
    image   =   models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/media/photos')
    date    =   models.DateTimeField()`
```

template page:

```
`   {% for post in object_list %}
        <h5><a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a></h5>
        <img src="{{ post.image.url }}">
        <h1>{{ post.image.url }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}`
```

Comment: What url shows up in the `<title>`?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it is related to your `MEDIA_URL` settings. Check the terminal output and look for the request to the image, there is a good chance you've not set that, and/or you've not added the media url handler to your urls.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Answer (score 0):

You must set the **media** folder path in the settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

or add media root on url.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Is there a **blog/media/photos** folder path and accessable?